# Node v5 breaks Webstorm's debugger

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

Node has released its (not so) stable v5 version some days ago. I notice that when I try to run a node project with Webstorm with the debugger it I get the following exception on startup:

```
Cannot stop on breakpoint due to internal error: 
org.jetbrains.v8.V8CommandProcessor$1: TypeError: f is not a function
at Function.t.getScopes (eval at undefined, :217:15)
at t.describeFrame (eval at undefined, :213:33)
at t.getFrames (eval at undefined, :114:89)
at DebugCommandProcessor.r.processDebugJSONRequest (eval at undefined, :348:15)
```

I don't have other environments to reproduce this error. The programs continues to run but it doesn't stop on breakpoints anymore. Any idea for a fix for this?

UPDATE: I have opened a ticket with Jetbrains and they said they will fix this with a patch asap.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This issue is described [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/1659) and the workaround is described [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139990)

Basically add 
Workaround: Specify jvm system property:

`-Dnodejs.debugger.use.jb.support=false`

in your idea.vmoptions file.

Comment: This setting + babel-node makes the debugger take ages to startup on an average sized project - 3 mins for my project, every time i want to re-run it. But the debugger works after this, so it's something, ta!

Answer (score 6):

In my case I copied `/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/bin/webstorm.vmoptions` to `/Users/somename/Library/Preferences/WebStorm10/webstorm.vmoptions` and added `-Dnodejs.debugger.use.jb.support=false` line.
Result file was:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx1000m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Dnodejs.debugger.use.jb.support=false
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it in mac as editing the .vmoptions and .properties file directly will violate the application signature. More on that here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties?flash_digest=34602b13ae3437ee0082be25c1a685cb7554349c

Answer (score 5):

Please update to WebStorm 11.0.1, it works with Node.js 5 just fine

Comment: I've update to WebStorm 11.0.1 but I still have the problem, any ideas?

Comment: @IdoRan did you try setting `-Dnodejs.debugger.use.jb.support=false` in your idea.vmoptions file?

Answer (score 0):

Use 6.0.0 version, Its working fine there.